# Express routes planning if I want to get/update everything

Tags: node.js, express

Built only simple express backend before, now the new React project needs to load projects/tasks/users on first enter. should I just make a route like `api/everything`, or make three separate `GET` calls to `api/project` `api/task` `api/user`?
(BTW, I'm trying to follow REST practice yet now fully understand it, all tutorial I find focuses on concept and 'to do not to do' but no detailed demo.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are using react then projects,tasks,users are all different components, so it makes more sense to have 3 different apis. On the other hand if all of these are a single component or these data are interrelated and/or has to rendered at same time it would make more sense to have a single api returning all data.